# Single-column user defined variable based on a comparison

Tags: mysql

I have a database with over 300k lines and each row is a separate timed event.  I have a column of system spec values for error, followed by a stochastic draw on an actual error for that event.  I can change the confidence level for the actual error by multiplying the actual error by a constant.

I have tried this query and while it returns a 1 in each error code, what I am looking for is a way to develop a user defined variable called “myerror” that is filled by each rows error * the constant.

sample query statements:

```
((select(actual_error * “constant”) <= lowest_threshold) as level_1_error,
((select(actual_error * “constant”)  between this and that) as level_2_error,
((select(actual_error * “constant”)  between higher_this and higher_that) as level_3_error,
…
…
…
((select(actual_error * “constant”) >= highest_threshold) as max_error,
```

What I’m trying for is something like:

```
Case when (select(actual_error * “constant”) <= lowest_threshold  set @user_error  =  “level_1_error”
          when (select(actual_error * “constant”)  between this and that) set @user_error  =  “level_2_error”
```

but, alas…..can’t seem to get it to work…..I’ve tried putting the set statement in a sub-query and just using a sub-query to select a different error level also…..

help bitte sehr.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE {x}` for the table structure, some sample data, and expected output. You description is quite hard to follow.

Comment: *each row is a separate timed event.* Does this mean that there exists some timestamp field in table's structure, and it is unique?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to create static, temporary or dynamic table which contains the adjacent border ranges for each error level normalized with “constant” value to avoid additional calculations (schema):

```sql
CREATE TABLE error_level_ranges ( level, lower_bound, upper_bound )
AS 
SELECT 1,-1,2     -- 2 as "lowest_threshold"/constant,
                  -- assume -1 is below min possible value of actual_error
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,10     -- 10 as "that"/constans, assume "this"="lowest_threshold"
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,10,25    -- 25 as "higher_that"/constant, assume "higher_this"="that"
-- ... 
UNION ALL
SELECT 99,100,999 -- 100 as "highest_threshold"/constant, assume levels count < 99
                  -- and 999 is over max possible value of actual_error
```

and then

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.level
FROM error_events t1, error_level_ranges t2
WHERE t1.actual_error >= t2.lower_bound
  AND t1.actual_error < t2.upper_bound
/* or alternatively, dependent by a real logic
WHERE t1.actual_error > t2.lower_bound
  AND t1.actual_error <= t2.upper_bound */
```

If you have a lot of error categorization schemes with different level counts and their borders, you must add a field (named similar to `categorizing_scheme`) into `error_level_ranges` table and proper additional expression like `AND t2.categorizing_scheme=@current_scheme` to conditions section.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is inside out:

```
SELECT
    Case when actual_error * “constant” <= lowest_threshold     THEN “level_1_error”
         when actual_error * “constant”  between this and that  THEN “level_2_error”
         ...
         END AS Level
  FROM ...;
```